# tf.keras save_model sometimes works and sometimes don't

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: fashion_mnist_model0/variables; No such file or directory 

in TensorFlow 2.0 using Windows 10.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XpPQiSbJpVr8up66l93YUdAWty6Kd2k0
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15BlkiQOd5zUCgNRfKs1tXbsk4o898wG9
Edit:Same notebook works in Colab but cause error in my PC

```
def func1(optimizer=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 20, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'valid',input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.compile(loss= "categorical_crossentropy",optimizer = Adam(), metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return model
def func2(model_filename = 'temp_s0',model = None):
    if (model == None):
        model = func1()
        #with open(model_filename,'wb') as file :
            #pickle.dump(model,file)
        save_model(model,model_filename)
def func3(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,model_filename):
    model = func1()
    save_model(model,model_filename)
```

func2() works well gives:
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: temp_s0\assets

However, for some reason, the following code doesn't work:

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
func3(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,model_filename = "fashion_mnist_model0")
```

gives :

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-499ddb13879f> in <module>
----> 1 model , y_train_1 , y_test = func3(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,model_filename = "fashion_mnist_model0")

<ipython-input-34-48cc1e442911> in func3(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, model_filename)
      1 def func3(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,model_filename):
      2     model = func1()
----> 3     save_model(model,model_filename)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
--> 115                           signatures, options)
    116 
    117 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options)
     72   # default learning phase placeholder.
     73   with K.learning_phase_scope(0):
---> 74     save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
     75 
     76   if not include_optimizer:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\save.py in save(obj, export_dir, signatures, options)
    897   # the checkpoint, copy assets into the assets directory, and write out the
    898   # SavedModel proto itself.
--> 899   utils_impl.get_or_create_variables_dir(export_dir)
    900   object_saver.save(utils_impl.get_variables_path(export_dir))
    901   builder_impl.copy_assets_to_destination_dir(asset_info.asset_filename_map,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\utils_impl.py in get_or_create_variables_dir(export_dir)
    181   variables_dir = get_variables_dir(export_dir)
    182   if not file_io.file_exists(variables_dir):
--> 183     file_io.recursive_create_dir(variables_dir)
    184   return variables_dir
    185 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py in recursive_create_dir(dirname)
    436     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    437   """
--> 438   recursive_create_dir_v2(dirname)
    439 
    440 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py in recursive_create_dir_v2(path)
    451     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    452   """
--> 453   pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path))
    454 
    455 

NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: fashion_mnist_model0/variables; No such file or directory
```

---

for some reason, I don't know

Comment: It can't find the file so it's loading it as `None` which then can't be unpacked.

Comment: Why it produces different output in two functions that are mostly the same?

Comment: Changing the file name also doesn't work but it gives a different error

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a **permission problem** rather than a **programming** problem.

You could try running your Jupyter Notebook with Admin privileges.

**Command prompt** (Admin)

1. Search `cmd`, then `Run as administrator`. from there you can go to the environment (conda env or virtualenv) or execute your code directly (jupyter notebook).

**Anaconda Prompt** (Admin) if using Conda distribution.

2. Search `Anaconda Prompt`, from there you can go to the environment (condo env or virtualenv) or execute your code directly (jupyter notebook).